# Set number of div elements' width based on static width container

Tags: html, css

I want to set the width of the div elements' width accordingly depending on their container width. However, the number will be changed, so the width will need to be adjusted accordingly. Here is a CSSDeck link to explain the situation clearly:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/hvmkapkd

As you can see, both containers are identical (needed), also they have modular content (`<div>` elements) (which is also needed). Keeping the same structure, is it possible to auto adjust the width of the divs using CSS so that they fill up the whole container?

Then each item in the first container would have 33.333% width, and each item in the second container would have 20% width.

Comment: is it acceptable to use js? jquery?

Comment: I was looking for a pure CSS solution, I just found it and posted it as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution right after posting the question.
Setting the `.container` elements as `table` and setting the colored content as `table-cell` made it.

Link is updated above, but here is the link once again anyway:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/hvmkapkd

Answer (score 1):

Give the flex-box concept a chance (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

```
.container{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 20px;


/* flexbox setup */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

.container > div {
  height: 100%;

/* flexbox setup */  
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

(http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/hvmkapkd)